# Are there any third-party libraries to write your own rsyslog server?

Tags: c++

Right now in Ubuntu 16.10 I have rsyslog sending some "marked" iptables packets to file. However, I'll have to send them over network to another machine ("log aggregation") and another machine should be able to parse them.

Are there any libraries for C++ which help receiving logs from remote machines and working with them? Or how should I properly receive rsyslog messages coming from the network?

It isn't necessary to use exactly `rsyslog`, maybe other syslog solutions (`syslog-ng` etc.) can be used. I just want to be able to receive syslog messages.

Comment: Regarding iptables marked packets.  Ulog2 from netfilter can log iptables based events to database mysql and etc.

Comment: All the source code is available for rsyslog, and you can copy the receiving bits out and put them in  your code.  Any server running on the rsyslog port will receive the event data, but processing it take more work.  Logstash is a pre-written complete log server.